# Clean up output of a command to pipe to notify-send

Tags: bash, scripts, vpn, .desktop, notify-send

Ubuntu 18.04

ExpressVPN has no GUI or icon for the Linux version. So I put together a .desktop files that and then added clickable buttons on my taskbar to trigger them. The .desktop files trigger scripts that run commands to connect the VPN, or disconnect it, or display a pop-up message indicating the current status.

It's the status one I need some advice on. The command to get the status is:

```
expressvpn status
```

When running that command in terminal, if the VPN is disconnected, what you see is:

[image: Not connected]

If the VPN is connected, what you see is:

[image: Connected]

My taskbar button triggers this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
MESSAGE="expressvpn status"
notify-send --expire-time=500 "`$MESSAGE`"
```

Now, this works. I get the information I need. But there's something about it that I don't like. It's not critical but I'd like to understand why it happens and if it can be changed.

It works great if the VPN is disconnected, I see a pop-up that says "Not connected":

[image: clean pop up message]

However if the VPN is connected, what I see is quite ugly. It looks like this:

[image: ugly pop up message]

If I write the same output to a text file, it contains this text:

```
[1;32;49mConnected to UK - East London
[0m
   - If your VPN connection unexpectedly drops, internet traffic will be blocked to protect your privacy.
   - To disable Network Lock, disconnect ExpressVPN then type 'expressvpn preferences set network_lock off'.
```

Ideally I'd like it to contain only the line in green shown in the above screenshot - "**Connected to [whichever connection is live]**".

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: PS I've tried adjusting the variable to MESSAGE="expressvpn status | grep -i connected". That command prints just the one line in terminal, but doesn't work in the script.

Comment: Are you asking how to use `head`/`cut`/`awk`/`sed` and similar shell-based formatting tools?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think so - Andy's message below about ANSI escape codes has gotten me closer to a solution but it's not quite working yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to colourise output. Getting rid of them is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) in general.

If you're able to install packages, `ansi2txt` from package `colorized-logs` as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527259) will strip them out.

Something like `expressvpn status | ansi2txt | grep -i connected` should give an output you can work with.

Comment: Thanks Andy. This has gotten me closer. Using that command to get the script to output `expressvpn status | ansi2txt | grep -i connected` to a text file produces a file with just the content I want to display, without the unwanted characters. However if I try to get notify-send to display the variable, the pop up contains an error message "**Incorrect usage: flag provided but not defined: -i NAME: e**" - it cuts off there so I'm not able to provide the whole error message.

Comment: @4n3wv I suggest you move the command inside the variable assignment and change the backticks to `$(...)` ex. `MESSAGE=$(expressvpn status | ansi2txt | grep -i connected)` followed by `notify-send --expire-time=500 "$MESSAGE"`

Comment: Thanks @Andy-J for the direction, and thanks @steeldriver for the refinement. That got it working. I've edited the script to `MESSAGE=$(expressvpn status | ansi2txt | grep -i connected)` followed by `notify-send --expire-time=500 "VPN status" "$MESSAGE"` to make it as pretty as possible.

Comment: Incidentally in the meantime I worked out a less elegant compromise by using another technique I found elsewhere. Outputting the text to a file and then using that file as the source of the notify-send content like this `expressvpn status | ansi2txt | grep -i connected > ~/vpnstatus` followed by `notify-send --expire-time=500 "$(basename "VPN status")" "$(cat ~/vpnstatus)"` - this got the same result but I prefer the simplicity of what @steeldriver suggested.